About Games and why they aren’t on the website
Why are there no games?
You know what? You don’t need to call it gamedev.stackexchange.com because there is no game!

If you are looking for games and not for talking/helping about the development of them, then you're on the wrong address

In "game development" key word is "development".

Have you played "There is no game"? It's pretty cool! :) Not even kidding.

This is a website for game developers to answer questions about game development asked by other game developers. It's a platform for us to help each other while we are making games, not for posting the games we make. Check the help center or take the tour for more information on what this website is for.

I'd add that if a user wants to find some games made by users here, we have several shown off and linked through past Winter/Summer Bash Showcase threads.
